# stored procedure passing date parameter getting error

Tags: sql-server

```
alter procedure [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReport] 
  @locid INTEGER, @startdate nvarchar(100),@enddate nvarchar(100)
 as
begin
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype)    
                     from VType_tbl FOR XML PATH(''), 
                     TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
set @query = 'SELECT Date, ' + @cols + ' 
  from  ( select v.Vtype, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
  from Transaction_tbl t inner join VType_tbl v  
   on t.vtid = v.vtid 
  where dtime between @startdate and @enddate
  and locid =  ' + CAST(@locid as varchar(max)) 
 + '  ) d pivot ( count(Vtype)     for Vtype in (' + @cols + ')  ) p '
execute(@query)
end
```

I am trying to execute like this:

exec ParkingDeatailsReport 5, '2013-01-01 00:00:00','2013-06-18 23:59:59'

but, I'm getting an error:Must declare the scalar variable "@startdate".

Comment: possible duplicate of [while executing stored procedure with date getting error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245230/while-executing-stored-procedure-with-date-getting-error)

Comment: Hint: If a question is closed, don't repost it with no apparent changes. Closure means that your question, as your currently asking it, is not suitable for this site. Usually, it means you need to put more effort into explaining what you're doing, or that you haven't provided any evidence of having performed any research

Comment: sir,,,i try that ,,still am getting error

Comment: insted of decalaring datetime i declared as nvarchar,,,but still am getiing error,,,why getting error while passing datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are building SQL in the proc, but you are not using the values in @startdate and @enddate, instead you are passing the string

You need to grab the values of these variables when you build the string - something like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReport] 
  @locid INTEGER, 
  @startdate nvarchar(100),
  @enddate nvarchar(100)
as
BEGIN
  DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
          @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

  SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype)    
                       from VType_tbl FOR XML PATH(''), 
                       TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

  SET @query = 'SELECT Date, ' + @cols + ' 
                FROM  ( 
                  SELECT 
                    v.Vtype, 
                    convert(date, dtime) as Date 
                  FROM Transaction_tbl t 
                  INNER JOIN VType_tbl v  
                  ON t.vtid = v.vtid 
                  WHERE 
                    dtime between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + @enddate + ''' 
                  AND locid =  ' + CAST(@locid as varchar(max)) + '  
                ) d 
                PIVOT ( count(Vtype)     
                FOR Vtype in (' + @cols + ')  ) p '

  EXECUTE(@query)
END
```

Comment: Thnaks sir,,,this stored procdure worked for me,,,,Thanking you very much,,,,